# Finding out all blocked port numbers

Tags: networking, port

The Internet connection in my hostel room is provided by my college which blocks a few ports (eg. 6881-6889 to prevent usage of torrents). I want to find out exactly which ports are blocked, because I'm doing a project which would probably require these ports. How to do this?

Comment: Best way is to ask your hostel's internet provider

Answer (score 1):

You could try to reach an external server that has all ports open like http://portquiz.net/

http://portquiz.net:80/

http://portquiz.net:81/

http://portquiz.net:6881/

This server listens on all TCP ports (and sends an http response), allowing you to test any outbound TCP port. `nmap portquiz.net -v -sT -pT:6880-6895`. (This particular one doesn't seem so stable though).